# How to prevent a dynamic width flexbox child from overflowing the parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the sample below, I want to prevent the streched child from overflowing the parent. I do not want to specify a width for it. How can I accomplish that?

```css
#flex-parent { display: flex; width: 200px; background: green; padding: 10px; }
#fixed-child { width: 20; background: red }
#stretched-child { background: yellow; word-wrap: break-word }
```

```html
<div id="flex-parent">
  <div id="fixed-child">
FIXED
  </div>
  <div id="stretched-child">
  STREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEECHED
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You hit the *min-width algorithm*, where the `min-width` of a flex item defaults to `auto` and as such doesn't allow it to shrink below its content.

You can use `word-break: break-all`

```css
#flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

#fixed-child {
  width: 20;
  background: red
}

#stretched-child {
  background: yellow;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-parent">
  <div id="fixed-child">
    FIXED
  </div>
  <div id="stretched-child">
    STREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEECHED
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or `min-width: 0` to allow it to be smaller than its content

```css
#flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

#fixed-child {
  width: 20;
  background: red
}

#stretched-child {
  background: yellow;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-parent">
  <div id="fixed-child">
    FIXED
  </div>
  <div id="stretched-child">
    STREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEECHED
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*After a quick cross browser test (Chrome/Firefox/Edge/IE on Windows 10), it appears IE need either the `word-break: break-all` or `overflow hidden`*